# USB auto-suspend Issue

Tags: usb, suspend

I use Ubuntu 16.04 and when I put my computer into suspend mode, the USB port does not turn off and my peripheral's LED keeps flashing. I tried several solutions but they just didn't work. Such as

```
echo 'on' > /sys/bus/usb/devices/*/power/level
```

How can I solve this issue, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I realized that there is a jumper on my motherboard for activating the "Wake up on Ps2/USB" option  which would power the USB till the system is powered on so I just moved the jumper to the appropriate place and the Problem solved!